# Syntax error when printing result using MIPS

Tags: syntax-error, mips, spim

I'm relatively new to MIPS and am using SPIM as my compiler. The program I am trying to write takes a user's input of a decimal integer and determines how many zero's and one's are in the binary representation of it:

```
        .data
ques:   .asciiz "Enter a decimal integer:\n"
zer:    .asciiz "Number of 0's\n"
one:    .asciiz "Number of 1's\n" 
buf:    .word   16
ans:    .word   40
        .text
        .globl main

#Prompt user for number
main:
         la      $a0, ques               #asks user to enter decimal integer
         li      $v0, 4
         syscall

#Read the input
        li      $v0, 5                  #reads user input
        syscall
        move    $s3, $v0                #stores user input in register
        jr      count                   #jumps to count function

count:
        addi    $s7, $s7, 1             #increments with each run of the loop
        beq     $s7, 32, end            #checks if all parts of the binary integer have been checked
        andi    $s0, $s3, 1             #ands one to binary number
        beq     $s0, 0, zeros           #goes to incrementing function for 0
        beq     $s0, 1, ones            #goes to incrementing function for 1

zeros:
        addi    $s5, $s5, 1             #increments 0 counter by one
        srlv    $s3, $s3, 1             #shifts binary digit right by one
        j       count                   #returns to count function

ones:
        addi    $s6, $s6, 1             #increments 1 counter by one
        srlv    $s3, $s3, 1             #shifts binary digits right by one
        j       count                   #returns to count function

end:
        la      $a0, zer                #Prints zeros header
        li      $v0, 4
        syscall
        la      $a3, $s5                #prints number of zero's
        li      $v0, 1
        syscall
        la      $a0, one                #prints ones header
        li      $v0, 4
        syscall
        la      $a3, $s6
        li      $v0, 1
        syscall
        jr      $31                     #end program
```

My problem is that when I try to print the results of my program, I get a syntax error:

```
spim: (parser) syntax error on line 43 of file test.mal
          la    $a3, $s5                #prints number of zero's
                  ^
```

I've tried a number of things to fix this, but I'm not really even sure what the problem is. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`la` is "load address" it expects the 2nd parameter to be a label.  I think you just want to use a simple `move $a3, $s5` here.  Also, if I remember correctly, for syscall 1, you want to put the integer to printed in $a0, not $a3.  Finally, I find MARS *much* easier to use than SPIM: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/